# React Native, IOS Simulator Error opening simulator. Check Metro log for details

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, visual-studio-code, ios-simulator

So there is my issue.

I've just created a React native project On my M1 macbook air, a blanck project.

yarn start work fine, but when i want to open with an IOS simulator i havr this error : "error opening simulator check metro logs for details"

Also, when i try to open directly to ios simulator in VS code (tape i after yarn start) i have that :

> Opening on iOS...
> Opening the iOS simulator, this might take a moment.
> (node:2690) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: open exited with non-zero code: 1
> at ChildProcess.completionListener (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/src/spawnAsync.ts:65:13)
> at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
> at Socket. (internal/child_process.js:439:11)
> at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at Pipe. (net.js:673:12)
> ...
> at spawnAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/src/spawnAsync.ts:26:19)
> at Object.openSimulatorAppAsync (/@expo/xdl@59.0.14/src/SimControl.ts:308:16)
> at ensureSimulatorOpenAsync (/@expo/xdl@59.0.14/src/Simulator.ts:185:22)
> at Object.openProjectAsync (/@expo/xdl@59.0.14/src/Simulator.ts:674:14)
> at ReadStream.handleKeypress (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/start/TerminalUI.ts:228:11)
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
> (node:2690) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 4)
> (node:2690) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

So if anyone have a clue, i've tried to change .expo username with : "sudo chown -R MYUSERNAME /Users/MYUSERNAME/.expo/" (apparently it solve this issue for someone else but not me..

Thanks in advance, i'm just starting with react native, and start with this kind of error it's quite frustrating.

Comment: Update : Problem solved by running : expo client:install:ios

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update : Problem solved by running : expo client:install:ios